# How to add search in Power Bi slicer having a numeric field as a slicer value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-datasource

I have a power Bi Slicer in a report . The field which I am using in that slicer is of numeric type. It has many values to filter from and I want to have a search box.

Now for the other slicer values having text field, when I click on three dots I see a search option .But I don't see the similar thing in numeric slicer.

Now changing the data-type might solve the problem, but I am using direct query and it is not allowing me to.

Kindly suggest a way I can add search in power bi numeric slicer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not supported yet. The ugly workaround will be to use slicer as "between" option and type same value in "from" and "to"